# slmtest in R - Error non-conformable arguments

Tags: r

I'm running panel regression models in R with the specified model:

```
  tot_crime <- log_rt_crime ~ ndvi + log_disad_inde + log_density
```

I've successfully run:

1. non-spatial OLS pooled model using plm

   ```
   pooled_nosp_crime <- plm(tot_crime, data = final_long_panel, model = "pooling")
   ```
2. non-spatial individual fixed effects (within) model using plm

   ```
   FEwithin_nosp_crime <- plm(tot_crime, data = final_long_panel,
                     model = "within", effect = "individual")
   ```
3. non-spatial individual random effects model using plm

   ```
    REgls_nosp_crime <- plm(tot_crime, data = final_long_panel, 
                   model = "random", effect = "individual")
   ```
4. Hausman test using plm

   ```
   hausman_nosp_crime <- phtest(tot_crime, data = final_long_panel)
   ```
5. Hausman tests robust to spatial autocorrelation using splm

   ```
   hausman_sp_crime <- sphtest(tot_crime, data = final_long_panel, 
        listw = queen, spatial.model = "error", method = "ML")

   hausman_sp2_crime <- sphtest(tot_crime, data = final_long_panel, 
           listw = queen, spatial.model = "lag", method = "ML")
   ```

So far so good. however, when i run the LM test for spatial lag dependence:

```
slmtest(tot_crime, data = final_long_panel, listw = queen, 
        test = "lml", model = "within")
```

I get the following error:

> Error in X %*% coef(mod) : non-conformable arguments.

Any idea what may be causing this error?

```
geoid           density     disad_inde  time    ndvi    rt_crime
170312909001    13035.08    2.33438992  1   0.31162748  97.70808203
170312909001    13035.08    2.33438992  2   0.49197907  106.1519903
170312909001    13035.08    2.33438992  3   0.4220205   100.1206273
170312909001    13035.08    2.33438992  4   0.13471775  95.29553679
170312909001    13035.08    2.33438992  5   0.3566384   95.29553679
170312909001    13035.08    2.33438992  6   0.4852591   97.70808203
170312909001    13035.08    2.33438992  7   0.48259588  90.47044632
170312909001    13035.08    2.33438992  8   0.17898722  92.88299156
```

Comment: Are points 1 to 5 at all relevant to the line of code that isn't working? I can't see anything in your `slmtest` that comes from those lines. If so, why are they there?

Comment: no, you're right, i left them in for completeness sake, and to indicate that the panel set and the weights [appear to be] set up correctly.

Comment: then it must be something intrinsic to your data and we don't know what's in it. Can we have your data or a subset or a sample set that illustrates the problem? Or an example that doesn't fail?

Comment: It would also help if you told us which packages the functions are coming from. The package names are also useful in the "tags" for the question. A little searching tells me it might be `splm`.

Comment: @Spacedman yes sir, you got it splm

Comment: @Spacedman Data sample added to my original comment. Two covariates are time invariant (density, disad_inde), and the main predictor is time variant (ndvi)

Comment: couple other notes in case they may be of help - 19 time points over 2179 geo units. the panel is balanced

Comment: You need to make your code more complete and dump spurious code and please, add required packages. We have no idea how your data was prepared before going into the function or what the data, in fact, looks like. Have you created a `pdata.frame` or a `plm` class object? Given `%*%` the function is likely failing as a result of the listw object that you are passing it but, we cannot see the characteristics of said object. It is unclear if `splm::splmtest` can accept binary, weights or either. What kind of Wij relationship does your matrix/list contain?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't order your dataframe (first by time, then by region), which is a prerequisite when applying spatial operations to your model. Try this:

```
dfo <- df[order(df$time), ]
```

and might be working then.